# How can i set the scope for a specific jar file in Apache ANT based project?

Tags: java, ant, jboss, jboss7.x

I need the CXF jar file that is present in the application source path to be used only for the code compilation and it should not be added into the war because i have already CXF jars that are predefined in the jboss 7.2 server. so my question is how can i set a scope for that jar in my application build file?

Comment: Put the .jar file in the classpath for `<javac>` but don’t include it in your `<war>` task.

Comment: I tried it but i am getting build error i.e package org.cxf does not exist

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you edit your question and include the part of your Ant build file which compiles, and the part which builds the .war.

Comment: Oh sorry VGR I cant post the code here as I am working in a client machine where they will track everything. I will edit the question in detail to make you understand it more clear.